# Why is dangerous to share metamask logs?

Tags: metamask, security, logs

Sorry for the noob question, but if the Metamask logs don't contain a secret phrase, why is it dangerous to share it online?
Also, can hackers get hold of my Metamask wallet logs without hacking my computer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the logs contain, but I would imagine it might not be a good idea to share those publicly because of the following possible issues:

1. They may contain data that can be used to identify you: IP addresses, connectivity data, usage patterns
2. They may contain some half-sensitive information, such as wallet addresses, wallet amounts, wallet types (hardware wallet or something else), and stuff like that
3. They may contain technical information which helps an attacker, such as information about some vulnerable browser version being used

I'm sure the logs don't contain any directly sensitive data, such as private keys, but still, it's not a good idea to share those publicly for the aforementioned reasons.

Comment: ok, got it. so I assume the only way someone can get hold of those logs is by hacking my browser or pc?

Comment: That's one way, yes. Or maybe some phishing site asks for the logs and you provide them.